# configuration JMeter wtth Jenkins by Docker container

Tags: docker, jenkins, jmeter, containers, docker-container

I  did functional tests in JMeter (backend application).
I have in Jmeter 42 functional tests and I launch this in one docker container
Now I configuration JMeter with Jenkins by docker container -
My dockerfile is following:

```
[https://pastebin.com/Aq9A9eqh][1]
```

To automatically run these tests regullary,
I created docker - container and when I run build execution on Jenkins, I had a following error:

https://pastebin.com/365kLWXB

1. What is wrong?
2. How is the best way to improve this?
3. What can I improve further?

I know that I must add a java jdk, but I don't know how to add to my dockerfile?

[https://pastebin.com/Aq9A9eqh](http://%20https://pastebin.com/Aq9A9eqh)

When I added:

```
FROM openjdk:8u162-jre-slim-stretch
ARG GITHUB_OAUTH_TOKEN
```

it didn't run.

Answer (score 0):

With regards to your current setup your Docker image doesn't have [Java installed](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jre8-downloads-2133155.html) therefore you cannot launch JMeter.

You can fix it by replacing these line:

```
RUN apt-get install -y git
```

with this one:

```
RUN apt-get install -y git default-jre
```

---

With regards to "improve further" be aware that according to [JMeter Best Practices](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/9-easy-solutions-jmeter-load-test-%E2%80%9Cout-memory%E2%80%9D-failure) you should always be using the latest version of JMeter so consider replacing JMeter version `3.3` with somethine more recent, as of now it's JMeter 5.0, you can always check [JMeter Downloads](https://jmeter.apache.org/download_jmeter.cgi) page for current release details.